# error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++

I just would like to ask what does this error mean and how to fix it thanks!

> error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std'

```
vector<int> result;
        for (auto & i : numbers)
            result.push_back(std::stoi(i));
        std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
```

Comment: //error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std'  on line 4

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @Blacktempel Ow ok thanks it worked. (Y)

Comment: @CjMedina Why not accept one of the answers you've gotten that says the same thing?

Answer (score 77):

Include the algorithm header. That's why there is a error.

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 21):

You have to `#include <algorithm>`. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).